# how to create a clean and scalable NSIS installer implementation out of a VB6 project?

Tags: vb6, installation, package, nsis

I am updating my installer from using the VB6 packaging & deployment Wizard to the NSIS installer.

The list of files my project uses are diverse, using different paths and types of files. For example,

```
File1=@drillcycles.pre,$(AppPath),,,8/30/10 10:23:54 AM,49152,1.0.0.1
....
File5=@techno1.TTF,$(AppPath),,$(Shared),12/6/06 10:14:56 AM,12704,0.0.0.0
....
File18=@MSCOMM32.OCX,$(WinSysPath),$(DLLSelfRegister),$(Shared),6/23/98 11:00:00 PM,103744,6.0.81.69
....
```

Initially, I was planning to `hard code every single file` into the NSIS script, but it would be cumbersome for a newbie in my team to actually update my code. It is hard to reuse and scale.

Then, I was planning to `create several folders for each respective path, as well as the type of process` that the file should go through. For example, an `app_path_selfregistered folder` in which I could drop the new files and just recompile my installer. I felt that it was not really scalable and clean solution.

Finally, someone suggested me to create an `external script` that I would call, but I am not sure how to implement it nor what would be the advantage over my first approach.

Any ideas how to cleanly create a scalable NSIS installer in which I can easily update to new files as well as newer versions of them?

Thanks

Comment: I have used the script method in the past.  Just create a script in your favorite language that replaces the file section of part of your NSIS script, with a list of files in a specific directory.

Comment: @Brad: what would be the advantage of creating an external script, over just hard coding it into the NSIS script?

Comment: The advantage is to save you the time of manually putting in a file list.  That's all.  Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: When you add a file to your source project, do you "just drop it" in a folder? Or do you use a tool to add it to a project? Can someone that does not understand what's he doing add a file to the project?

Comment: @wqw: I picture it as future developers knowing the software structure, but not necessarily familiar with NSIS. That said, they should be able to easily repackage the software without changing anything in NSIS. makes sense?

Comment: @Brad: That is one part, but the second is to know what to do with that file. For example. where should it be copied (path)?, should it be registered? That seems to have to be defined somewhere. I was looking for an easier way to do it.

Comment: @Peretz, you can write a script to define all of these things, but if you have specific requirements for each file, it sounds like it will be easier just to write the NSIS script in the first place.  I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Brad: I imagine I was searching for a better approach that writing it in NSIS, but given my conditions it seems to be the best option. Thanks.

Comment: @Peretz: Treat NSIS (or setup) scripts as source code. Keep it under source control, peer review it, test it, document it. Don't let anyone who doesn't understand what he's doing prepare your setup which is the first thing users/admins see of your application.